# Firebase function issue?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

> i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
>   Warning: You're using Node.js v8.10.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
>
> ⚠  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
>
> ⚠  functions: Error from emulator. Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '/home/developer/Development/host2/functions'
>
> Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.

We are  new in firebase function , How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you try as it says to run the `npm install` inside of your local functions folder?

Comment: yes, and nothing happened

Comment: and `npm i --save firebase-functions` inside of the folder also?

Comment: 303  sudo firebase serve --only functions,host
  304  cd functions
  305  npm i --save firebase-functions
  306  cd ../
  307  ls
  308  sudo firebase serve --only functions,host
  309  npm i --save firebase-functions

Comment: not working, it still shows     i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
Warning: You're using Node.js v8.10.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.
⚠  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside the functions directory.
⚠  functions: Error from emulator. Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '/home/developer/Development/host2/functions'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.

Answer (score 5):

In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK. It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and the SDK with these commands inside the functions folder of your Firebase project:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
```

visit: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my problem was the same as your, but for further reference I will post my solution.

In my case, I was using `TypeScript` instead of `JavaScript`, so the code needed to be compiled before run `firebase serve`.

In your Firebase app directory:

```
$ cd functions/
$ npm run-script build
$ cd ..
$ firebase serve
```

The last command maybe need super user permission, so `sudo firebase serve`.

Optionally you can run `npm run-script lint` before `npm run-script build` to check for possible errors if you are using `tslint`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was :

1 - Reinstall Node ( version 10.15.0 ). After download node-v8.11.2-x64.msi from node.org

2 - Reinstall firebase-tools ( npm install firebase-tools -g )

3 - Clear cache ( npm cache clear --force )

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem too. I can't explain how, but it turns out that my `firebase.json` was not correct. Check the functions section of it and make sure it looks like this:

```
"functions": {
    "source": "functions"
},
```

Found this SO answer: [How to deploy functions from other directory than '/functions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916633/how-to-deploy-functions-from-other-directory-than-functions)