# Where does firebase CLI stores functions folder path?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

When initializing a firebase project, it creates a firebase.json file containing settings for hosting, firestore, storage, but nothing for functions. When deploying, the firebase CLI correctly finds the functions. Does the CLI goes through the whole project looking for functions or does it store the functions' folder path somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase CLI by default assumes that the Cloud Functions for your projects are in a `functions` folder under the project folder.

You can override this by specifying a `source` value in the `functions` configuration in `firebase.json`.

Also see Doug's answer here: [How to deploy functions from other directory than '/functions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916633/how-to-deploy-functions-from-other-directory-than-functions)

Comment: Thank you. After Check the mentioned answer there's more to firebase-tools than I thought, it would be great if it had a section in docs/guides.

Comment: In that case, this link is probably your new favorite: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file :)

Comment: I have been searching for this property all around.. including firebase docs.... thanks!